# how to remove gridlines for subticks for log scale

Tags: d3.js

I have made a graph with log scale for which there are grid lines in the background. The grid lines are drawn for the sub-ticks also which i want to remove. can anyone know how to do it. I have tried it using linear scale also but it wasn't looking proper on the log graph. Please suggest some tricks. Thank you.

Here is the link to image of the graph:
http://snag.gy/24j4i.jpg

Below is my code to generate grid lines

```
            function make_x_axis1() {
                return d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(x)
                .orient("bottom")
                .ticks(12)
                }

            function make_y_axis1() {
                return d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(y)
                .orient("left")
                .ticks(8)
                }
            svg1.append("g")
            .attr("class", "grid")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(make_x_axis1()
            .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
            .tickFormat("")
            );

            svg1.append("g")
            .attr("class", "grid")
            .call(make_y_axis1()
            .tickSize(-width,0, 0)
            .tickFormat("")
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the `.tickSubdivide` setting on your `axis`.  There are a bunch of examples at http://bl.ocks.org/GerHobbelt/3605035.  This seems to be the relevant one that you are looking for:

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x minor endticks classical log_x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + axis_y + ")")
    .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(log_x).tickSubdivide(example_subdiv_A(log_x))
      .tickSize(12, function(d, i) {
        return (2 * d.subindex == d.modulus ? 8 :
                ((5 * d.subindex == d.modulus) && (d.modulus >= 10) ? 6 :
                 ((d.subindex % 2 == 0) && (d.modulus > 10) ? 5 :
                  (d.modulus > 10 ? 2 : 4))));
      }, -10))
    .call(descr("classical logarithmic, with output-dependent # of subticks, emphasis on the 2nd and other even (but only when we have 10+ subticks!) and .5 subdiv, and longer start/end ticks"));
```

Here he varies not only the number of subticks but also their size. If you don't want the subticks at all, you can set `tickSubdivide` to 0 to remove them. If you want them just as ticks on the axis, you'll need to use `.tickSize` and do a little math to set the tick mark size for major tick marks separately from minor tick marks.

Comment: I have used .tickSubdivide(). But i am not bothering about axis ticks. I want to remove the grid lines formed by the sub-ticks on the axes. Thank you very much for your help Bill.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem today and found a solution. I created a function to remove those gridlines manually. The gridlines which you want to remove are the one that does not have the text value.

```js
    function removeNoNameTicks(logAxisSelector) {
        var targetAxis = d3.select('g.x.axis');
        var gTicks = targetAxis.selectAll('.tick');
        if (gTicks.length > 0 && gTicks[0]) {
            gTicks[0].forEach(function (item, index) {
                // find the text if the text content is ""
                var textElement = d3.select(item).select('text');
                if (textElement.html() == '') {
                    item.remove();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```